# The Reminders on my Mac is not working

Tags: catalina, reminders

I recently upgraded my Mac to the Catalina Os. Since then, the reminders are not working on my Mac. But once I click on the Reminders it is showing an error and redirecting me to login. Post login also, it is showing the same error. For now this is just happening with Reminders. Is there an issue with the OS Catalina installation?

Comment: What's the error?